# Maps API: zoom the map by drawing a marquee box?

Tags: here-api

Does the HERE Maps API for JavaScript support marquee zoom?

(i.e. let the user draw a box, then zoom the map to that box)

Comment: I'm limited on time so I'm sorry I can't give you a full answer. I think this would help you though - https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/resizable-geoshapes/resizable-rect. I'm going to try to build this for you next week (going on vacation) and will post back if I do. Again, I'm sorry I can't do more.

Comment: @RaymondCamden, no worries.  I ended up implementing it with an HTML <div> element on top of the map to display an interactive box.

Comment: Cool! Glad you got it!

Answer (score 0):

There's UI control called [ZoomRectangle](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.ui.ZoomRectangle.html) which does exactly what you need:

```js
// assuming, that ui is instance of H.ui.UI
let zoomRect = new H.ui.ZoomRectangle();
ui.addControl('zoomRectangle', zoomRect);
```